# Plax.js not working when the window scrolled from middle to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

You can see here ( http://straightupstaging.com.au/uk-caravans/foxtail/ ) that the eagle image and plane image is working correctly with `plax.js`.

But when you scroll your browsers window unto middle to bottom the fish image doesn't working correctly with `plax.js`.

Comment: Add some example code so that we can replicate the issue and so that we have a reference in case the link is not longer usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used plax.js but reading the code I came across the following:
Line 262:

```
if (!inViewport(layers[0].obj[0].parentNode)) return;
```

It would seem that they check if the first element in your plaxify collection (in your case the eagle image) is still in view. If it is not then it does a return; and therefore does not carry on with the "animation".

This same behavior could be seen in their official demo:
http://projects.cameronmcefee.com/plax-demo/
where if you make your browser window smaller and scroll down it stops working.

I have created a js fiddle with a slight rework of that if statement in order to check if any of the layers are in view

```
var elsInView = false;
$.each(layers, function(k,v) {
    if (inViewport(v.obj[0].parentNode)) {
        elsInView = true;
    }
});
if (!elsInView) return;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lo6qqg6x/1/

Or you could probably just comment it out. Hope this helps.